# ASP.NET MVC 4.0 GolbalFilter for page request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, action-filter

I want to capture site traffic in my ASP.NET MVC 4.0 website.
I have done this

**My Base Controller:**

```
 public class BlogActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
                BaseModels.StoreSessionData(filterContext);
            }
        }
```

**Global.ASAX:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {

            // Register global filter
            GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new BaseController.SiteActionFilterAttribute());
}
```

So far everything works pretty good.

if my action view has any Render Action or Action helper, then my session event is storing another new record in my db, this is because my Global filter is for **`ActionFilterAttribute`**.

If one page request has more than one action then, my session event will capture all those actions as events.

How can I restrict my filter to work on per-page-request but not Action and its sub actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you properly, you want to restrict the types of Actions for which you StoreSessionData. I assume one such type you want to restrict is ChildActions. If so, here is how you would do so"

```
 public class BlogActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
                if (!filterContext.IsChildAction)
                    BaseModels.StoreSessionData(filterContext);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I believe that requires the method to be marked as a child action, does it not?

Comment: @MystereMan, yes it definitely does. Is there a more definitive way?

Comment: @MystereMan same question, is there a more definitive way? even if i have not used child action attribute.

Comment: From everything I've checked, no other way seems to exist

Comment: Your answer helped me to get close to what I want. So I am marking your answer. Thank you.